# pdftex does not look for pfb files

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I tried to install a custom font to my system (LY1 encoded for my purposes), and found that pdftex cannot find it. It crashes with the following message

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+480/600 --dpi 480 bfui8y

The command name is C:\Users\Lemaitre\Documents\pdftex\bin\mktexpk
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

though I added the corresponding map file like this:

```
bfu8y Sample-Book " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bfu8a.pfb
bfui8y Sample-BookItalic " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bfui8a.pfb
bfubi8y Sample-BoldItalic " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bfubi8a.pfb
bfub8y Sample-Bold " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bfub8a.pfb
```

and ran `updmap` as prescribed. `dvips` and `dvipdfm` can process the font flawlessly.

For some weird reason `pdftex` does not even look for the `type1` directory to search for the outline font, so it falls back to bitmaps, unsuccessfully, of course.

Comment: what happens if you add `\pdfmapline{=bfui8y Sample-BookItalic " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bfui8a.pfb}` to your document?

Comment: after getting some sleep, and reading another q/a, I figured there might have been another pdftex.map lurking somewhere: and a simple `find` confirmed my guess. alas, `kpsewhich` only reports the first file it finds, and does not check for duplicates. I'm I right?

Comment: look it is your problem and you want help. So try to be a bit more verbose.

Comment: my apologies. I'll process an answer, perhaps as an answer to a similar question.